# User Agent String parsing for CPU and RAM

Tags: python

I need to get RAM/CPU data from given user agent strings. While I know that you cannot tell exactly the specs, given the string, I was wondering if there was a Python library or 3rd party software that could parse User Agent strings and give estimated CPU and RAM. If not, is there a database somewhere where I could look up device names (gotten from the UA strings) to get this info? Thanks!

Comment: Common user agent string for browsers don't contain any information about hardware, just about the OS and browser. Not something a library can even guess from that alone.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I figured. Do you know of any tools/apis that would allow one to search a device and get the hardware specs?

Comment: @KDackow Have a look at browser fingerprinting techniques, but from the user agent string on its own it's simply not possible, there is no information sent there at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up writing my own code to do this. It is still pretty basic, but it can be found here [repo](https://github.com/KevinDackow/user-agent-device-class).